# Unable to initialize size of vector along with contents

Tags: c++, vector

The code below is just the isolated problem. I want to not only reserve the size of the vector but also initialize the contents so that if a vector element within the size range is suddenly assigned a value, it won't throw a vector subscript out of range error. I'm basically replacing a fixed-size array that is used throughout a large amount of code and I want the same functionality without having to add "item.push_back(newItem)" to throughout the file. I tried putting a for loop inside the Node constructor that just added  but for some reason the .push_back() method was unrecognized.

How would I not only reserve the size, but also initialize the contents within the constructor?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

int maxSize = 3;

struct Item{
    string key;
    string value;
};

struct Node{
    int count;

    vector<Item> items;

    Node()
    {
        items.reserve(maxSize + 1);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Item item;
    item.key = "Hi";
    item.value = "there";

    Node *p = new Node();

    p->items[1] = item; // Error: vector subscript out of range

    cout << p->items[1].key << " " << p->items[1].value << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reserving only allocates underlying memory, for purposes of optimisation. If you don't know you need it, you don't. If you don't know you need it, and you wrote it, you shouldn't have done.

What *you're* trying to do is make the vector actually take on a size, and fill up with elements that you can immediately access via `operator[]`.

To do so, write [`resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) instead of [`reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve).

In fact, since you're doing so on a member in the constructor of its container, what you really should be doing is initialising the vector by calling its proper constructor:

```
struct Node
{
    int count;
    vector<Item> items;

    Node()
      : items(maxSize + 1)
    {}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `resize` instead of `reserve`